# Apache (httpd) Wont start because "could not open error log"

Tags: apache, apache2.4

ok guys, im stumped. I install centos 7.2 on a vm, installed httpd, enabled it as a service, then started it
then created and edited  a config file as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
ServerName www.mydomain.com
ServerAlias mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html
#ErrorLog /var/www/mydomain.com/error.log
#CustomLog /var/www/mydomain.com/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So.. When I uncomment the "ErrorLog", which I believe is correct, and there is a file called error.log in directory "/var/www/mydomain.com/"
Httpd.service doesn't want to start, with the error:

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/mydomain.com/error.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I tried doing chown on the error.log file, to apache:apache, and root:root, and the user for the site, but that didn't work. 
I also made sure to 755 the directory for www, so the error.log file should be able to be opened by that. Help me out please

Comment: UPDATE: So I did find it had something to do with selinux being enabled.
I used
setenforce 0
then tried: "systemctl start httpd.service"
and it started right up. so question, how do i fix that?

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that the error and access logs needed to be placed in /var/log/httpd/ instead of where they were.

Answer (score -1):

All the directories in the path leading up to the error.log must have the executable and readable bit set for the apache user or group, in order for apache to be able to write to the log file.

In order to debug the permissions, you could su to the apache user, and try touching the file:

```
sudo -u apache touch /var/www/mydomain.com/error.log
```

Comment: I did touch the file /var/www/mydomain.com/error.log

Comment: also, as root: typing
sudo -u apache -i
gives me this error "This account is currently not available"

Comment: its not available because httpd is running also, but its only running because i commented those parts out. so i still have the problem of course

Comment: _This account is currently not available_ is reported because the apache user has no shell. Pardon me. Try just `sudo -u apache touch /var/www/mydomain.com/error.log`.

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work and gave out the same error in apache for not being able to open the log /var/www/mydomain.com/error.log

Comment: Since you are now saying that selinux is your problem, have a look at the thread here: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1742